# json search within list

Tags: jquery, json

i have a json document kind of like this:

```
{
   "randomName":[
      [
         "need1",
         "dont need",
         dont need
      ],
      [
         "need2",
         "dont need",
         dont need
      ],
      [
         "need3",
         "dont need",
         dont need
      ]
}
```

jquery
....after calling json into p...

```
for (q = 0; q < p.randomName.length; q++) {
  $('<option/>', {
    value: p.nandomName[q],
    text:p.randomName[q]
  })
  .attr('class', 'subj')
  .appendTo('#myid');
};
```

what i get is first loop the hole first index, secon loop the hole secon index... any help on how to get only the item i need?

Comment: check your console.. Your json is invalid , missing `]` in your json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each item in `randomName` is another array, so I believe you want this:

```
text:p.randomName[q][0]
```

(I assume the issues with your json are only present in your question here, and not in your actual code.)

Comment: its exactly that, thank you, i dont know why i didnt try that, so if there were a list inside that list i could just continue putting indexes?

Comment: Yes, `p.randomName[q]` returns an array, so you access the items by index. If `p.randomName[q][0]` returned an array, you could access _those_` items by index. As a side note, if you have access to change the json, I would suggest considering changing `p.randomName` to an array of objects instead of an array of arrays. I find that easier to read/maintain.